# How to get summary count with cache enable on all pages footer?

Tags: magento2.2

I am unable to get summary count with php code when cache is enable.

I used below code.

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getSummaryCount();
?>
```

Comment: instead of `$this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');` you should try it `$this->helper(Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart::class);` make sure clearing cache after making this change.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with cache enabled, all files aren't re-interpreted.

You should get it with javascript. You can try to add the following code in your phtml file (the following example is to show you the way) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        'use strict';

        customerData.get('cart').subscribe(function (cartInfo) {
            console.log(cartInfo['summary_count']);
        }, this);
    });
</script>
```

This code will print nothing where there isn't product in cart, and cart count when there is products.
It will be triggered every times that the cart is updated.

Comment: thanks, but i need php code if possible.

Comment: Then you have to do it with an ajax call, or by using a section (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)
Other solutions inovlve disabling part of the cache, which is not recommended